# could php7-fpm strtotime ever think this date '4/10/2019 13:54:21' as invalid input due to server load?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, lamp

The mysql database(5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (Ubuntu)) reports that i am inserting '1969-12-31 16:00:00' instead of '2019-04-10 13:54:21' into a table in the database.

However, since there is proof that the request that hit the apache2.4 server and then got processed by the php7-fpm workers included this date '4/10/2019 13:54:21'.

I am left bewildered as to why it did not go into the database like this '2019-04-10 13:54:21'. After this code ran:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('4/10/2019 13:54:21'));
```

This record is going into the table via a stored procedure, however i verified that the params are going in correctly, since another date went in there fine.

```
new_record | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_record`(
IN p_account_id integer,
IN p_order_id integer,
IN p_unit_id integer,
IN p_begin_date datetime,
IN p_end_date datetime,
IN p_duration integer,
IN p_status integer
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO schedule
    (
        schedule_id,
        orders_id,
        units_id,
        schedule_begintime,
        schedule_endtime,
        duration,
        status_id
    )
    SELECT 0, p_order_id, p_unit_id, p_begin_date, p_end_date, p_duration, p_status
    FROM units AS u
    JOIN properties AS p ON(p.properties_id = u.properties_id)
    WHERE u.units_id = p_unit_id AND p.owners_id = p_account_id;
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as post_id;
    COMMIT;
END | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | utf8_general_ci
```

Create table looks like this for table in question:

```
| schedule | CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `schedule_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `units_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `schedule_begintime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `schedule_endtime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`schedule_id`),
  KEY `orders_id` (`orders_id`),
  KEY `units_id` (`units_id`),
  KEY `status_id` (`status_id`),
  KEY `schedule_begintime` (`schedule_begintime`),
  KEY `schedule_endtime` (`schedule_endtime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Curiosity has me posting here since i cannot think of:

Why the date would not get accepted as valid by strtotime?
Mysql inserts a default date in there?
There is modification to the array which houses this date value but not modification to this specific key?

The other oddity is that this only happens for one of the users.

Has anyone experienced issues like this? Could they occur due to server load?

Comment: **What Happened On December 31 1969??**
When your software/web application is showing you December 31, 1969, this suggests that most likely there’s a bug somewhere and the Unix epoch date is being displayed.

Comment: With other words show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` structure and rest of your PHP code.

Comment: I'd eliminate the `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('4/10/2019 13:54:21'));` piece of code because - what's `4` in that date? Month or day? What's `10`? Month or day? We've got awesome tools since a decade ago. I'd go for `$date = (DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '4/10/2019 13:54:21', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. Not only are you not dependent on your server's time zone and locale, you have complete control over time zone, format, locale and what not. If that part is eliminated from the equation, you can focus on another part of the app.